# How to list files in an order?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looping on the following files

```
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-55:52.lofar4.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar2.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar3.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:47.lofar1.ar.pscr
```

After the loop, I want to list them in an order as:

```
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:47.lofar1.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar2.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar3.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-55:52.lofar4.ar.pscr
```

After listing them in this way I will be able to apply my conditions on them.

Note that, I only care about the part lofar1, lofar2, lofar3 and lofar4 in the file name(the other part of the file names may not be the same but it doesn't matter in my case, I only need to list them using the part lofar1,2,3,4). Once I set them in an order that's it.

Comment: Are there more than 10 of them? Said another way, are they all numbered 0 through 9?

Comment: No, they all either four (*.lofa12.ar.pscr, *.lofar2.ar.pscr,  *.lofar3.ar.pscr *.lofar4.ar.pscr ) or three files not more than this.

Comment: Is the 12 in your comment a typo for a 1?

Comment: Yeah, yeah! is a typo, I meant "1".

Comment: why not      `ls -1 | sort`   ?

Comment: I tried it. didn't work.

Comment: @user1133275 : Because he doesn't want to have them sorted alphanumerically. Look at his desired output: They are not sorted. Actually, Sparhawk gave a suggestion how `sort` can be applied here.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls | sort -t. -k3
```

- -t. means delimit possible sort keys by full-stops (American periods)
- -k3 means sort by third key 'field', your lofar*

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ls | sort -t. -k3
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:47.lofar1.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar2.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-15:46.lofar3.ar.pscr
J0139+5814.2015-02-15-55:52.lofar4.ar.pscr
```

### Explanation

- `ls |`: pipe the output of `ls` to the `sort` command.
- `sort -t. -k3`: sort the output of `ls`.

  - `-t.`: the delimiter ("field-separator") is `.`
  - `-k3`: we are sorting from the 3rd field, which is `lofar…`